# Can a semantic prime have a homophone which is also a semantic prime?

Tags: semantics, homophony, natural-semantic-metalanguage

If semantic primes which are homophones exist, is it possible to create sentences which have perfectly valid interpretations which differ?

I'm thinking of something like a "meaning" hash-collision which is also a "sounding" hash-collision(homophones).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is the case with the BE (somewhere), BE (someone/something) and BE (mine) primes. But I'm not sure you could make a whole sentence with two of these that are otherwise identical. The primes each have their own distinguishing contexts.

Comment: Can you elucidate regarding BE (mine)? 
It looks like you read the wiki article and replaced "is" with "BE".

Comment: @whickey BE (mine) is an older label I think. Either way it doesn't make a substantive difference. NSM has the concept of allolexes where the prime will be inflected in different contexts. BE will appear in English NSM explications as IS or ARE or AM.

Comment: Note that "NSM" stands for [Natural Semantic Metalanguage](https://www.google.com/search?&q=natural+semantic+metalanguage), a theory associated with [Wierzbicka](https://www.google.com/search?q=Wierzbicka) and [Goddard](https://www.google.com/search?q=cliff+goddard). It's a good theory but not as well known as it ought to be, imo.